# is plotkml no longer updated for current R release?

Tags: r, gpx

I am attempting to use plotkml to read gpx files and plot them using R. Many others have done this with great success. A few examples are below:

https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2014/03/running-paths-in-amsterdam-step-2.html
http://flowingdata.com/2014/02/05/where-people-run/

However it seems like when I try to download the package it no longer is updated to work with the current release of R. I get the error you see below:

> install.packages("plotKML", repos=c("http://R-Forge.R-project.org"))
>   Installing package into ‘\peter/users/My Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning message:
>   package ‘plotKML’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)

How do I read in the gpx lat long data besides using plotkml's readgpx function?

I am a beginner when it comes to this sort of computing and just trying to get this visualization to work as a starter.

Comment: Install the plotKML package from [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=plotKML) with `install.packages("plotKML")`

Comment: Many are moving their development from R-Forge to GitHub so, it is not surprising that it is no longer maintained on that repository. Always check CRAN first, otherwise you may be installing an unstable development version.